# impossible to run jquery script when div is loaded, run jquery code before DOM load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, load

I've looked for many solution but I can't find one... Can you help me ?
I want to run a code when a div is loaded. I don't want to wait the end of the loading page.

So I'm using the  `$(sel).on('load', function(){ ... });` It's working when I'm putting `$(window).on('load', function(){ ... });` but not when I specify the ID of the div `$('#collapseTrack').on('load', function(){ ... });`

**Here is all my code :** `

$('#collapseTrack').on('load', function(){

```
$('#nav-maps').on('click', function(event) {           
    $('#nav-maps').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    $('#nav-trace').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');           
});

$('#nav-trace').on('click', function(event) {           
    $('#nav-trace').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
    $('#nav-maps').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');           
});



$('.collapse-nav').on('click', function(event) {

    $('#collapseTrack').toggleClass('DivClose').toggleClass('DivOpen');

    if ($('#collapseTrack').hasClass('DivClose')) {

        $('.collapse-button').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>');
        $.cookie("toggle", 0, { expires : 10 });
    }

    else {

        $('.collapse-button').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>');
        $.cookie("toggle", 1, { expires : 10 });
    }


});



if ($('#collapseTrack').hasClass('DivClose')) {

    $('.collapse-button').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>');

}

else {

    $('.collapse-button').html('<i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>');

}
```

});

`

Thanks !!!

Comment: div's don't `load()`. you don't need an event, you can either see the div or you can't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific `.load()` event for a single div.  So, the only time you can actually find the `#collapseTrack` div in your code is if you run some code after that div has been parsed and added to the DOM by the page loader or when it has been added to the page by some Javascript code.

The simplest way to run code right after that div has been loaded is to place a `<script>` tag right after the `<div>` in your HTML.

```
<div id="collapseTrack">Your HTML</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#collapseTrack')....
</script>
```

Since the page is parsed sequentially, this ensures that all HTML that appears before this `<script>` tag in the page is already in the DOM and accessible before this `<script>` tag runs.

---

If you're willing to wait until the page itself has been parsed to the end, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // waits for just the DOM to be finished parsing and inserted
    $('#collapseTrack')....
});
```

That will at least run earlier in the loading process than the `window.load` which waits for all page resources to finish loading (including images, style sheets, etc...):

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // waits for all page resources to finish loading
    $('#collapseTrack')....
});
```

Comment: @BenjaminOlivier - Did you get a solution to your issue?  If so, please mark this (or some other answer) as your selected answer by checking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and this will indicate to the community that your question has been answered and will earn you some reputation points that can earn you more privileges over time here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jfriend00, it solved my problem !
A simple question of logic once again !

Answer (score 1):

put script tags after the div

```
...html here...
    <div id="your div">foo</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       //code here
    </script>
...more html here...
```